# Central ac secondary line

Tags: hvac

my secondary condensation line is dripping from my garage ceiling . I have had them come 2 times to clear it with forced air . I also changed filters . They just left for a second and when I turned on the ac and it is lightly dripping . They told me if that didn’t work they would have to take something apart to get to the pan and it would be expensive. Any advice ?  It is humid today. I am at a loss at this point . I just bought this house a few months ago and have never had central air before. Ac is cooling perfectly .

Answer (score 1):

There should be at least an access hatch so you can add some biocide tablets to the drip pan.

What’s probably black gunkies are growing in the pan and blocking the flow.

Black gunkies are my name for the dust and organic growth that is quite common in the evaporator drip pan.

If they just blew air through the tube the gunk will float back to the outlet and keep plugging it a simple spider web across the opening or being submerged can cause the tube to not drain properly,

There are biocide tablets that will kill the gunkies and do not create health hazards. the biocide tablets only cost ~$10 for enough for a entire cooling season, areas that have a longer cooling season may need more but your home store usually sells them in an amount that is needed for your area.

Comment: Are you referring to these? https://www.amazon.com/Nu-Calgon-4296-60-Pan-Treat-Scum-Tablets/dp/B003N5AS60 If so, do you know if they're safe for use in a condensate pump resevoir?

Comment: @monkeyzeus   Those are similar to what I use.  I like nu-Calgon but those sound a bit expensive to me (I don’t see the size and usage)  if the tablets are similar to what I use that is a lifetime supply, probably do the job fine. The ones I use last 4-6 weeks depending on the amount of condensate. I use them in systems that drain into pumps and have never had any problems so putting them in the pump tray should work but they might not last as long being submerged verses a little moisture on the bottom.

Comment: Shouldn't the primary line be draining all the condensate so it never gets into the secondary? If the secondary drain is dripping into the garage, it means the primary is plugged or is leaking into a large external pan and from there into the secondary drain line to outside. If the secondary is dripping inside, then it is either plugged or is leaking.

Comment: And the reason I suggested the tablets @jim Stewart

Comment: Do the tablets go into the primary, inside the coil housing?

Comment: Yes they sit in the pan, when there is moisture they release a small bit of chemical the more water the more chemical. These are required in commercial systems to prevent legionnaires as that was the original cause was the stagnant water in a large air conditioning system.

Comment: @EdBeal It's 200 tablets for $33.21. My main concern with a condensate resevoir is that the tablet might break down too fast and clog the pump. "Condensate pump tablets" seem considerably more expensive.

Comment: @monkeyzeus that is exactly what I said. The number of tablets may not mean anything if the tablets are the size of an aspirin they won’t last but a tablet 1+ inches across will usually last at least a month in most systems 6-8 weeks is not uncommon in my area and that is a majority of our summer in the PNW.

Comment: I am having a different person come and I will ask him about these tablets . Someone else suggested that my coil might be shot .

Comment: Renay the person that suggested the coil might be shot has very little knowledge, the pan being plugged is common even in brand new systems. If being plugged up that is quite common! If at some time a filter was not used the coil could be plugged up with dust then a cleaning is in order. Low air flow can cause the coil to ice up and when the system is not running the ice melts and the melt can cause problems. I have never found a functional system that the evaporator coil is shot, worst case a coil cleaning is needed followed by regular treatment of the pan to prevent gunkies from growing.